# R - Turn date values into positive integers

Tags: r, datetime, posixct

hope someone might point me in the direction of a solution to my specific problem.

Suppose I have a data frame, in column A I have dates of format (YYYY-MM-DD, POSIXct), which are between some start and end point (i.e. 2017/01/01 to 2018/01/01). In column B I have a list of items, and in column C I have the quantity of an item on the date given in A. Additionally, I want to add the assumption that although the dates in column A run between a known start and end-date, and are in order, they are not necessarily separated by equal time intervals. An example might look like this:

```
+------------+-------+----------+
|    Date    | Item  | Quantity |
+------------+-------+----------+
| 2017/01/01 | Beans |        2 |
| 2017/01/01 | Pens  |        4 |
| 2017/01/04 | Beans |        3 |
| 2017/01/04 | Pens  |        5 |
| 2017/02/01 | Tubes |        4 |
| 2017/02/03 | Beans |        9 |
+------------+-------+----------+
```

What I would like to do is add a column that turns each date in column A into a positive integer which corresponds to the number of days since a given start date. For example, if the start date is 2017/01/01, I want to add the following column

```
+------------+-------+----------+------+
|    Date    | Item  | Quantity | Days |
+------------+-------+----------+------+
| 2017/01/01 | Beans |        2 |    1 |
| 2017/01/01 | Pens  |        4 |    1 |
| 2017/01/04 | Beans |        3 |    4 |
| 2017/01/04 | Pens  |        5 |    4 |
| 2017/01/08 | Tubes |        4 |    8 |
| 2017/01/09 | Beans |        9 |    9 |
+------------+-------+----------+------+
```

Is there a simple solution that makes use of R's internal date/time handling (particularly number of days in the month/leapyears etc...)

Here is the dput() as requested by commenter

```
structure(list(date = structure(c(17167, 17167, 17170, 17170, 17174, 
17175), class = "Date"), item = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L), 
.Label = c("Beans", "Pens", "Tubes"), class = "factor"), quantity = 
c(2, 4, 3, 5, 4, 9)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Thank you in advance for your help, I hope my question is understandable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# Example data (please make it reproducible like this in future questions):

yourdata <- 
  data.frame(Quantity = c(2,4,3,5,4,9),
             Item = c('Beans', 'Pens', 'Beans', 'Pens', 'Tubes', 'Beans'),
             Date = c("2017/01/01", "2017/01/01","2017/01/04", "2017/01/04", '2017/01/01', "2017/01/09")
  )


yourdata$difftime <- sapply(yourdata$Date, difftime, yourdata$Date[1]) + 1
```

> ```
>   Quantity  Item       Date difftime
> 1        2 Beans 2017/01/01        1
> 2        4  Pens 2017/01/01        1
> 3        3 Beans 2017/01/04        4
> 4        5  Pens 2017/01/04        4
> 5        4 Tubes 2017/01/08        8
> 6        9 Beans 2017/01/09        9
> ```

This also works on the `dput()` data you added:

```
yourdata <- structure(list(date = structure(c(17167, 17167, 17170, 17170, 17174, 
                                              17175), class = "Date"), item = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L), 
                                                                                        .Label = c("Beans", "Pens", "Tubes"), class = "factor"), quantity = 
                             c(2, 4, 3, 5, 4, 9)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))

yourdata$difftime <- sapply(yourdata$date, difftime, yourdata$date[1]) + 1

yourdata
```

> ```
>         date  item quantity difftime
> 1 2017-01-01 Beans        2        1
> 2 2017-01-01  Pens        4        1
> 3 2017-01-04 Beans        3        4
> 4 2017-01-04  Pens        5        4
> 5 2017-01-08 Tubes        4        8
> 6 2017-01-09 Beans        9        9
> ```

Comment: Thank you, very clear answer. I have added dput() as requested, but you already got there with your solution. Will make it reproducible in the future as requested. Thanks again.

Comment: @SportScientist Happy to help! Could you please click the green checkmark to mark this as the solution?

Comment: You could do this without `sapply` too `difftime(yourdata$Date, yourdata$Date[1], unit = 'day') + 1`

Answer (score 1):

Just subtract off the minimum and add 1. This will work regardless of row order, etc. It does assume your data is of `Date` class (as in your `dput`). If your data is `POSIXct` class I'd recommend coercing it to `Date` class first or else the difference will be in seconds. Calling your data `dd`:

```
dd$days = as.integer(dd$date - min(dd$date)) + 1
dd
#         date  item quantity days
# 1 2017-01-01 Beans        2    1
# 2 2017-01-01  Pens        4    1
# 3 2017-01-04 Beans        3    4
# 4 2017-01-04  Pens        5    4
# 5 2017-01-08 Tubes        4    8
# 6 2017-01-09 Beans        9    9
```

Comment: Thank you for that snippet of clarification between the two classes. In the actual data I am working with I will coerce to Date class as suggested.

Comment: Yeah - your question seemed to confuse the concepts of "format" and "class", and mentioned POSIXct, which is a date-time class, but your `dput` data is of class `Date`, so it seemed worth it to be a little specific. "Format" really only matters if it is of `character` class and has yet to be converted to an appropriate class like `Date` or `POSIXct`. And there's not really any advantage to using `POSIXct` for a date, it is only needed if you have a time too.

Comment: Thank you, that is really helpful. I haven't worked with dates/times before in R, and there is still a lot I do not know, so your comments clarify a lot for me, and hopefully anyone else who has the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
transform(dat,dif=as.numeric(difftime(date,date[1],units = "days")+1))

        date  item quantity dif
1 2017-01-01 Beans        2   1
2 2017-01-01  Pens        4   1
3 2017-01-04 Beans        3   4
4 2017-01-04  Pens        5   4
5 2017-01-08 Tubes        4   8
6 2017-01-09 Beans        9   9
```